# URL issue & format issue Magento

Tags: magento

Site URL: [www.coreautomotiveequipment.com](http://www.coreautomotiveequipment.com) Working on a site and using Magento commerce. When adding custom URL to the cmd-pages-homepage I'm having a problem getting the urls to work.

I type in the store URL in magento, however when clicking the link on the site something different pops up. I have the `WYSIWYG` disabled completely so I'm not sure why it is changing.

Also the tag for the Air compressor is showing up at the bottom of the page. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code i have entered into the Magento content section:

```
<div class="col-left side-col">
<p class="home-callout">&nbsp;</p>
{{block type="tag/popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"}}</div>
<div class="home-spot">
<p class="home-callout">&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>


<script src="{{skin url='js/camera.js'}}"> </script>

<script>
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#camera_wrap').camera({
        alignmen: 'topCenter',
        height: '49.42%',
        minHeight: '134px',
        loader: false,
        pagination: true,
        loaderStroke: '2',
        fx: 'simpleFade',
        navigationHover:false,   
        pagination:false,   
        thumbnails: false
    });
});
</script>


<div class="fluid_container_wrap">
    <div class="fluid_container">
        <div class="camera_wrap camera_orange_skin" id="camera_wrap">
            <div data-link="{{store url=‘tirechangers.html'}}"  data-src="{{skin     url='images/camera/slides/slide11.jpg'}}"></div>
            <div data-link="{{store url=‘lifts.html'}}" data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/slide21.jpg'}}"></div>
            <div data-link="{{store url=‘air-compressors.html'}}" data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/slide31.jpg'}}"></div>
            <div data-link="{{store url=‘nitrogen-machines.html'}}" data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/slide41.jpg'}}"></div>
 <div data-link="{{store url=‘used-equipment.html'}}" data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/slide51.jpg'}}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="banner-block row">
    <li class="span3">
        <a href="{{store url=‘tirechangers.html'}}">
            <img src="{{skin url='images/media/banners-11.jpg'}}" alt=""  />
            <p><span>Tire Changers</span></p>
        </a>
    </li>
   <li class="span3">
        <a href="{{store url='lifts.html'}}">
            <img src="{{skin url='images/media/banners-21.jpg'}}" alt=""  />
            <p><span>Lifts</span></p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span3”>
        <a href="{{store url=‘air-compressors.html'}}">
            <img src="{{skin url='images/media/banners-31.jpg'}}" alt=""  />
            <p><span>Air Compressors</span></p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="banner-block row">
    <li class="span3">
        <a href="{{store url=‘nitrogen-machine.html'}}">
            <img src="{{skin url='images/media/banners-41.jpg'}}" alt=""  />
            <p><span>Nitrogen Machines</span></p>
        </a>
    </li>
   <li class="span3">
        <a href="{{store url=‘used-equipment.html'}}">
            <img src="{{skin url='images/media/banners-51.jpg'}}" alt=""  />
            <p><span>Used Equipment</span></p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
        <a href="{{store url=‘brake-lates.html'}}">
            <img src="{{skin url='images/media/banners-61.jpg'}}" alt=""  />
            <p><span>Brake Lathes</span></p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, the suggested edits do not fix the problem. The same thing shows up....